# Replace NaNs in masked numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
var[np.isnan(var)] = 0.0

var.shape
(50, 360, 720)
```

I want to replace NaNs in the array with 0.0. However, I get an error: `*** IndexError: Index cannot be multidimensional`

```
var[0]

masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = nan)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nan_to_num](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) is the right way to do it. Here's a 2D example:

```
In [25]: arr = np.array([[10, 20], [np.nan, 30], [np.nan, -10]])

In [26]: arr
Out[26]: 
array([[ 10.,  20.],
       [ nan,  30.],
       [ nan, -10.]])

In [27]: np.nan_to_num(arr)
Out[27]: 
array([[ 10.,  20.],
       [  0.,  30.],
       [  0., -10.]])
```

I believe `nan_to_num` should work on masked arrays as well. For example:

```
In [33]: mx = ma.masked_array([np.nan, 2, 3, 4], mask=[0, 0, 1, 0])

In [34]: mx.compressed()
Out[34]: array([ nan,   2.,   4.])
```

And now:

```
In [36]: np.nan_to_num(ma.masked_array([np.nan, 2, 3, 4], mask=[0, 0, 1, 0])).compressed()
Out[36]: array([ 0.,  2.,  4.])
```

Comment: @user308827: it really shouldn't. what makes you think so?

Comment: In my full dataset, it is converting everything to 0.0

Comment: @user308827: see my update to the answer. Maybe something is wrong with your dataset (all NaNs?) -- check it step by step